# Convergence of: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^n \cdot n^n}{(n!)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Convergence of:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^n \cdot n^n}{(n!)^2}$$

Tried ratio test but somehow it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Ratio test does give the answer. Please show what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Using
$$\left( \frac{n}{e}\right)^n \lt n! $$
we have
$$\frac{3^n \cdot n^n}{(n!)^2} \lt \frac{3^n e^{2n}}{n^n}$$
Then by root test ..

Comment: Yeah, nvm, I got it. Had an error in my solution

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\frac{3^n \, n^n}{(n!)^2}\implies \log(a_n)=n\log(3)+n \log(n)-2\log(n!)$$ Use Stirling approximation
$$\log(a_n)=n (-\log (n)+2+\log (3))-\log (2 \pi  n)-\frac{1}{6
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Use it twice and continue with Taylor series
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=(-\log (n)+1+\log (3))-\frac{3}{2 n}+\frac{5}{6
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1} } {a_n}=e^{ \log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)}=\frac{3 e}{n}-\frac{9 e}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Comment: this is convergent, right?

Answer (score 0):

For this series,

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{3^{n+1}(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!^2}\cdot\frac{n!^2}{3^{n}n^{n}} = \frac{3(n+1)(1+1/n)^n}{(n+1)^2}<\frac{3e}{(n+1)}\to 0.$$

By the ratio test, this series converges (with gusto).